# Garbage Collection information with Hadoop Jar

Tags: java, hadoop, garbage-collection

Is there a way to see the garbage collection information when running a jar file using hadoop? e.g.:

```
$ hadoop jar test.jar
```

I tried to `-verbose:gc` flag with the above command but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop hides the Java invocation, you can try to use:

```
$ export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xloggc:gc.log"
$ hadoop jar test.jar
```

Hope it helps